# Obj-C, refreshing part of a table after uploading the array holding its rows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In certain circumstances, I need to delete one or two records in my table view.

Rather than call `reloadData` is there anyway I can refresh from a say 6 rows down the table, from my data array ?

I really don't want to call reloadData as this will loose the users position in the table.

I'm not using core data and don't have time to re-write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableView's `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` does what you want.

If you want to delete some rows you could do something like this:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

NSInteger rowToDelete = [self.objects indexOfObject:foo];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToDelete inSection:0];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.objects removeObject:foo];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is. You can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` but if you are deleting from your data model you will need to do something like this:

```
NSArray *rowsToDelete = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section], <etc> , nil];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToDelete withRowAnimation:<pickYourPosion>];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Changes to your table view and data model must be made in sync. Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40)